# Sails.JS - MIME type text/html

Tags: sails.js

I got this error in console : 
"Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: 
".../images/regbackground.jpg"."

So, why is that? Why, type of images by request is getting "text/html" ?

I didn't have that problem without using Sails..

Comment: How are you sending the image?  Is `images` in the `assets` folder?

Comment: yeah, it's assets/images/regbackground.jpg getting by CSS file like background-image: url('/images/regbackground.jpg') no-repeat; and by HTML like <img src="/images/regbackground.jpg"> which also didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just realise right now that there is something wrong with my app, I created a new one, put a image and there were no problem at all... So, this can be closed.